# How can i cast an Object in mobiaccess?

Tags: mobile

I am playing around with mobiaccess framework, but i am stuck when i try to cast an Object to Integer.

Is it possible to cast in mobiaccess?

I tried to below code but it does not work:

```
var i:Integer =  (Integer) objectClass;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the square bracket "[]" like this:

```
var i:Integer =  [Integer] objectClass;
```